# Check existence of a common combination in multiple "large" dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

I have a data frames with multiple tables like the below.

Each table is very large. Each table can have certain number of variables. Different tables could share or even not share different number of common variables.

As each table size is large, so how could I "efficiently" find if there is an x, y, z,t for the example below that exists in the multiple tables . That is not a simple merging. Which means if each table share some variables with at least one other, then after merging, it is not empty. If table that don't share variables with others, it can also be taken care of.

I just want to know the existence, don't want to retrieve them

```
x 
0  1
1  2
2  3

  x   y
0  0  0
3  1  2
4  2  2

   x  z
0  0  0
1  3  6
2  5  2

   x  y   z
0  1  0   3
1  8  6   3  
2  5  9   1

   t  
0  2  
1  1   
2  5
```

How can I get the expected results?

Comment: So if any of the columns is present in a table, you wish to do what? 
Can you show us one of these tables and the expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The tables are samples results. Each sample iteration, the tables are different. For each iteration, if there exists a combination, the count will add 1. When divided by total number of iteration, that is a way to get expected values. I tried to merge the tables until the stage that could be merged further to check if it is unempty or not in each iteration.